# Is there a way to wait for an external event in a durable function without replaying a long running task

Tags: c#, azure-durable-functions

I have a problem which requires a long running task to be performed immediately, then a quick task to be performed at a later point using the result of the long running task. I thought I could do something like this with an Azure durable function:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var myThing = LongRunningTask();

    var result = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<object>("SomeEvent");

    myThing.DoSomething(result);
}
```

I misunderstood how functions work and now realise that my long running task is replayed every time the external event is fired. This is obviously not the desired behaviour.

Is there any way to achieve what I want with durable functions - or some other type of resource? Unfortunately in this instance the result of the long running task (`myThing` above) cannot be serialised  which I think would have simplified things.

Comment: Why cannot you call `LongRunningTask();` asyn too?

Comment: @MKR I don't understand why that would make a difference. I just want to avoid replaying the longrunning task when the external event is triggered.

Comment: @MKR thanks for the help but I'm not sure if it really solved my problem.

Comment: What's problem in new approach? Obviously, you can use it only if `LongRunningTask` is async. Hence, if that function is developed by someone else then its limitation.

Comment: @MKR the problem is that durable functions seem to work by replaying the entire function when the external event is called so the long running task will be triggered again. Also I don't think you're meant to make `async` calls outside of the durable context. so that rules out `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I don't believe this is the right technology approach regardless.  Functions, durable or otherwise, should be idempotent event subscribers and should be able to be run over and over again.  If you need to ensure that it is only executed once, a queued message would be a much safer way to handle this.

Comment: @SBFrancies You can change the call to `LongRunningTask()` to `async` and check. Because as per rule `On each rerun, it consults the execution history to determine whether the current async operation has taken place. If the operation took place, the framework replays the output of that operation immediately and moves on to the next await`, operations which had been called `async` and already completed will not actually rerun.

Comment: @MKR the problem is that you can't just use the `async` keyword - it would need to be via an Activity function but since `mything` is not serialisable I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform anything other that simple, deterministic logic in your orchestrator. Move everything that uses I/O or is CPU intensive to activity functions. The results of activity functions are captured and replayed in the orchestrator, without re-running the activity function again.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var myThing = await context.CallActivityAsync<Thing>("LongRunningTask", null);

    var result = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<object>("SomeEvent");

    myThing.DoSomething(result);
}
```

```
// Thing needs to be serializable
public class Thing
{
    public string MyData { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something with MyData
    }
}
```

```
[FunctionName("LongRunningTask")]
public static async Task<Thing> LongRunningTask([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
{
    // do some long running work
    var result = new Thing { MyData = myResult };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for multiple tasks.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
              [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var myThingTask = Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());

    var wait =  context.WaitForExternalEvent<object>("SomeEvent");

    await Task.WhenAll(myThingTask, wait); //Both task and external event completed.

    var myThing = await myThingTask;  //Get the result from task (Its completed)

    myThing.DoSomething(result);
}
```